# Elite caretakers disguised as bathroom attendants

Tags: story-identification, dystopia

I'm looking for the title of a story about elite caretakers disguised as bathroom attendants, etc.

I thought it was by Ray Bradbury. It is **not** "The Marching Morons" by Kornbluth.

Comment: Do you have any more details about it? They is _really_ vague.

Comment: **Please [edit] this question to add more details** - *anything* you can remember might be helpful. You might like to read through [our](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9337/31394) [checklists](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9336/31394) and guidance - it may help you to remember things you didn't know you remembered!

Comment: @OrganicMarble Do you have a good answer for this? What is it?

Comment: @OrganicMarble Oh, right. I bet that's it. You should have posted that as an answer. Too late now. A poor question doesn't necessarily invalidate a good answer.

Comment: There is a matching story on librivix (neither Marching Morons nor the wino doctor discovering the black bag). But it's been a while.

Comment: Was it a novel or a short story?

Answer (score 12):

This is quite likely the novel *[Search the Sky](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?3979)* by Frederik Pohl and Cyril M. Kornbluth.

In it, a generational starship arrives on a faraway planet. It transpires that it wasn't their primary or even secondary target; a long lists of planets that should have been inhabited were found to no longer contain human life.

The protagonist, Ross, uses a secretly hidden FTL ship to search the known inhabited planets for the reasons why. He lands on a couple of planets that use alternative forms of government: one with a strict gerontocracy and another with a strict matriarchy. He picks up some passengers along the way, Bernie from the first planet, and Helena from the second. They find dr. Sam Jones from a world they first believe to be earth, but which turns out to be ruled by the Joneses. There they learn the formula "L-sub-T equals L-sub-zero e to the minus-T-over-two-N".

After finally arriving on earth, he is awed by all "advancements" until learning that most acts of immeasurable intelligence are actually acts of unfathomable stupidity.
Occasionally a mysterious blue light is seen that intervenes to prevent a catastrophe and Ross concludes that there must be mysterious rulers taking care of the people. He finally finds them.

> The attendant materialized and offered Ross a towel.
> "Dime? he said wearily.
> Ross fished absently in his pocket. "The thing that bothers me, Doc," he said, is that I know there are intelligent people somewhere around. I even know what they're doing, I bet. They're doing exactly what I tried to do: acted as stupid as anybody else, or stupider. I'd make a guess," he said, warming up, that if we could just make a statistical analysis of the whole planet and find the absolute stupidest-seeming people of the lot, we'd——"
> He ran out of breath all at once. His eyes bulged.
> He looked at the men's-room attendant, and at the ten-cent piece in his own hand.
> "You!" he breathed.
> The attendant's face suddenly seemed to come to life. In a voice that was abruptly richer and deeper than before, the man said: "Yes. You had to find us yourself, you know."

[ISFDB](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?3979), [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Search_the_Sky).

Comment: That's the one I was thinking of.

Answer (score 3):

Possibly "[The Little Black Bag](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?52216)", a third story by Cyril Kornbluth using his theme of a genius minority placed in self-imposed thrall to a moronic majority.

Most of this story takes place in the present, but there are parts set in the future, where a doctor is a moron who relies on the amazingly advanced tech of his medical bag. His bottle-washing acquaintance is one of the genius minority.

> Dr. Gillis was not aware of it, but "Mike" had an I.Q. six times his
> own and was -to be blunt- his keeper. "Mike" rode herd on the
> pseudo-physicists in the pseudo-laboratory, in the guise of a
> bottle-washer. It was a social waste - but as has been mentioned
> before, the supernormals were still standing at the approaches to a
> bridge.  Their irresolution led to many such preposterous situations.

Comment: @Jason Baker Can anyone please name a story ***not by Kornbluth*** about "elite caretakers disguised as bathroom attendants etc."? There must be a lot of them, seeing as five people voted to close this question for having "too many possible answers." Three related stories by Cyril Kornbluth is not ***my*** idea of "too many possible answers".

Comment: @user14111 perhaps a custom close reason, "too many possible Kornbluth answers"?